# how to generate a large pdf report using itextsharp c# library

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

How to generate a large PDF report using itextsharp C#? Say for e.g. i wanted to create a PDF file which contains around 5000+ pages? Without Memory exception?

```
 Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 0, 0, 10, 10);
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
pdfDoc.Open();

iTextSharp.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.HIGH_PRECISION = true;

PdfPTable PdfTable = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 30f;

if (headerContent != null)
{
    foreach (PDFHeaderItem item in headerContent.items)
    {
        PdfTable.AddCell(CreateTitlePDFCell(Lang, item.ItemHeader, fontHeaderFontAR, headerContent));
        PdfTable.SpacingBefore = 10f;
    }
}
```

```
//Columns headerCellFormats
for (int i = 0; i < 500000000 ; i++)
{
    PdfTable.AddCell(CreatePDFCell("TEXT", cell.KeyName, yourFont, cellFormats));    
}
```

```
 PdfTable.Complete = true;
pdfDoc.Add(PdfTable);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

Comment: you can use the [Large Table functionality on iText 7](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/large-tables). Check the second argument on the [API](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/dotnet/7.2.4/classi_text_1_1_layout_1_1_element_1_1_table.html#ab41fa41e2a45010f7e51fc08ba969205).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have the pdf table added to pdf document for every x no of records so that it free up the system memory, please refer the below code

```
for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++)
{
 PdfTable.AddCell(CreatePDFCell("TEXT", cell.KeyName, yourFont, cellFormats));
if (i > 0 && i % 5000 == 0)
{
    pdfDoc.Add(PdfTable);
}
}
```